# OSX (cocoa) -- time before changing desktop

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

Is there any chance to change the time needed to perform switch between desktops?

I mean, when you drag a window to the border of your screen it goes to your next (if there's one) screen/desktop. I want to turn it off or rather slow down so the time needed for a window to be dragged to the edge is longer.

I know I can run NSTask (with 10 sec delay as an example):

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-edge-delay -float 10.0; killall Dock
```

but if I want to see the change I need "killall Dock" and this makes the desktop goes black for a moment.

Does anyone know if there is another way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you changing the preference _back_ after you set it? Otherwise, your users might get annoyed with you. (: